# Need a way to display image and draw on the image in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

The current way that I found was to make a bitmap and paint it into a picturebox,
but there it is very slow when trying to scroll the panel (the picturebox is inside a scrollable panel).

Is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I know with the Winforms, there's a way to specify that the form should be double buffered.  I'm assuming this property has it's routes in the Win32 API, so it may be accessible from MFC as well.

Comment: It shouldn't be slow.  Why it is slow in *your* program is unguessable from your question.

Comment: Could it be that my image is pretty large? about 1500x2000px

Comment: Are you loading and drawing the bitmap in your `OnPaint` handler?

Comment: Yea, where else should I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the bitmap only when your picture box is created, then leave it in memory until the picture box is destroyed. Loading the bitmap every time `OnPaint` is called will destroy performance.

Also make sure you aren't re-painting your bitmap if you receive a `WM_PAINT` message and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

That image size, 1500x2000 will be slow. How about resizing it to 25% to show a preview and if a user wishes to see the whole image give them an alert it may take some time.